# Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException Route [games.mines] not defined. C:\private\gamble\resources\views\games\mines.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X10bJ.png)

so when i open my laravel i get this error: Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [games.mines] not defined. (View: C:\private\gamble\resources\views\games\mines.blade.php)

but when i remove the line: mines. my page will load in.
and im completely lost in how to fix this.

basically i just want to add a header with a button to my mines. the button to dashboard works fine

Comment: you don't have a route named `games.mines` ... did you name a route `games.mines`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try typing these instructions from the command terminal:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:cache
php artisan optimize
```

You may have a problem with the Laravel cache, these commands will clear the Laravel cache.

Comment: i dont know what it did but it did something good. thanks

Comment: @Delano `route:cache` as it re-cached the routes, but while you are in development you don't need your routes or config cached so just clear the route cache and you will not run into this again because they won't be cached, `php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 2):

The standard procedure to clear the Laravel cache is:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:cache
php artisan optimize
```

This is according to the following article: [https://beyondco.de/blog/laravel-caches-and-all-ways-to-clear-them](http://This%20is%20according%20to%20the%20following%20article:%20https://beyondco.de/blog/laravel-caches-and-all-ways-to-clear-them)